# Printer jobs can not be stopped

Tags: 11.10, printing, canon

Recently I had one of the most frustrating experiences with my printer.

I sent a some print jobs to my Canon Pixus iP3100 printer, but then realized there was a problem with the layout, and so I wanted to kill the print jobs. I went to this interface:

[image]

However, pressing the stop button, marked with the square, did *nothing*.

I tried everything I could think of to kill the print jobs. I tried restarting the printer. I rebooted the computer. I hit "reset" on the printer. I tried killing any printer related tasks in the task manager.

No matter what I did, though, the same jobs were in the queue, and the only way in the end that I was able to get past them was to have them all run through to the end.

Is this a bug, or is there some other aspect to this that I am missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open the terminal and type `lprm`.
This will clear the print queue and thus stop the printing.

Comment: lprm requests for localhost password. I have not set any password, If I use system password it says forbidden, even though I have the administrator options

Answer (score 10):

"`lpq -a`" will show you jobs on all printers (without the `-a` it will only show jobs on the default printer).

The third field of the output will be the job number, which you can use with "lprm" to cancel a specific job.

Here's an example.  PDF is my default printer, but not the one I sent my jobs to:

> [$] `lpq`
>   PDF is ready no entries
>
> [$] `lpq -a`
>   Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)
>   Total Size active  (null)  151     untitled
>   1853440 bytes 1st     (null)  153     untitled
>   100352 bytes
>
> [$] `lprm 153`
>
> [$] `lpq -a`
>   Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)
>   Total Size active  (null)  151     untitled
>   1853440 bytes

Comment: What tha heck. GUI failing me again, while CLI & askubuntu comes to the rescue. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

`lprm` did not work for me - there must be something strange about my Ubuntu install.

However, typing `cancel -a` in a terminal worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you hit that "Lock" button on the upper right, so you can unlock it?  I don't know - my printer controls are different - but I'm guessing that might give you access so you can kill jobs.

Comment: The unlock button is just so you can enter your super user password and then access the controls. Which I did, but was still unable to stop print jobs.

Comment: As I said, my controls are different (my printer's an HP).  I right-click the job I want to stop, and choose "cancel."  I imagine you tried that already, too, but figured I should at least mention it.